# using jquery UI - menu

Tags: html, css

I am using menu from UI
I have this `ul`

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Loans</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Bancassurance</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Aman el darb</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aman el elem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aman el ghad</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Audi Mobile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pin-Pay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ADSL Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bill Payment</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Internet Accesses</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Accounts</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Wedding Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Payroll Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Saving Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Current Account</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS :

```
.ui-menu-item { }
```

This select all li from `<ul id="menu">`
How should the css selector look like so I can select the submenu `ul inside of #menu

Comment: inside the JS, they are using a selection like this     mouseleave:
 "mouseleave .ui-menu": "collapse",      so i want to add another selection where i select all ul inside #menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your script use this `.ui-menu-item #menu ul{ }`

---

You can write like this

```
#menu ul li a{ css here}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GyS8r/1/)**

or

```
#menu ul li{ css here }
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/GyS8r/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you will need this

```
#menu ul {
}
```

If you need to target a specific UL inside of #menu, you should add an ID or Class to that particular UL and then reference it with this

```
#menu #example {
}
```

You can take it a step further and target each LI in the same fashion, like this

```
#menu #example li {
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: inside the JS, they are using a selection like this      mouseleave:
 "mouseleave .ui-menu": "collapse",       so i want to add another selection where i select all ul inside #menu

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you are trying to do, or post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the UL inside of #menu is pretty simple:

```
#menu ul { /*CSS HERE*/ }
```